# Breaker not resetting

Tags: circuit-breaker

Remodeling bathroom I took original light (set up by electrician) and put up a basic temporary fixture. No problems. Finished remodel and replaced temporary with original. Breaker won’t reset. I’ve taken down the light and capped the wires, tried reset but breaker wouldn’t reset, then replaced temporary, tried reset and still breaker won’t reset. This circuit runs half my basement. I’ve wired enough lights, fans etc to know I haven’t crossed wires.

Comment: Is the breaker that won't reset a simple breaker or is it an AFCI or GFCI? If it is an AFCI or GFCI (easy way to tell: it will have a Reset button in addition to a big On/Off paddle) then you may have a hot/neutral reverse, bad ground or other problem that may not be as obvious as a simple short.

Comment: It’s a gfci, had my basement wires by an electrician. All worked fine until I replaced the temp light with the original light. Had correct wires and even disconnected and capped the wires with no success

Comment: Does it not actually reset (breaker to the full OFF position to reset), or does it reset then immediately trip again?

Comment: If you turn the breaker off and on, does the **GFCI trip** or does the **overcurrent protection of the breaker** trip? If you put the temporary light back, does everything work?

Comment: Breaker won’t lock at all. Immediately snaps back to trip position

Comment: disconnect the wire from the breaker and try resetting

Comment: To me it sounds like you have a wire in the fixture grounding , the original worked then a temp up to this everything was fine, now another change. Metal boxes? If so I would be checking at the clamps that many changes and especially if your temp fixture was hanging by the wires it could be a grounded wire hot or neutral, but that’s where I would be looking.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to push the breaker all the way in the 'wrong' way then reset it. I don't know why this sometimes works but it has for me on multiple occasions

Comment: Originally I flipped it off so it was all the way. But also tried to push to fully off position a few times before reset and that didn’t work either

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's either a problem elsewhere on the circuit, a problem (like a nail/screw through cable) that came about just as you were finishing up the remodel, or the breaker has gone defective.

While I count the former two as more likely, you can check for the latter by swapping to another breaker of the same or smaller size (i.e. you can test a 20A with a 15A if the major loads on the circuit are not turned on, but not vice versa. You're just looking for "is it a wiring fault, or a bad breaker" not to run everything attached.) And you can check both ways if using the same size - swap the circuit to another breaker and the breaker to another circuit.

If it's one of the former two you are going to have to tediously hunt for it, by isolating parts of the circuit and seeing if the problem stays or stops.

Comment: Well I don’t like any of those options, heh. I did pull some can lights to paint the main room ceiling a couple weeks back. I’ll look at those but they seem pretty much plug and play. Otherwise I think I’ll let an electrician figure out those others possibilities